# how to dispose C# base class when derived class constructor generates an error

Tags: c#, constructor, dispose

If a C# derived IDisposable class constructor generates an error, how to dispose of the already fully constructed IDisposable base class?

Since all fields in the class hierarchy are initialized before any constructor executes, is it safe for the derived constructor to call base.Dispose()?  It violates the rule of not calling virtual methods until object is fully constructed, but I can't think of another way to do it, and my searching hasn't turned up anything about this scenario.

Comment: If it can be helped constructor should not throw an exception. Have an init method instead.

Comment: Constructors should not call virtual methods which are not required to be capable of handling partially-constructed objects.  Properly-written dispose methods for inheritable classes must generally be capable of handling partially-constructed objects, since that's the most practical way to prevent leaks.

Comment: @supercat: I didn't realize the virtual function table was in place before all the constructors ran.  Assuming the Dispose methods are written to handle partially constructed objects (mine are), you'd want to mark the derived class sealed so that someone doesn't inherit from that class and define a virtual dispose method in their class which did not handle partially constructed objects.

Comment: @jimvfr: Unless the derived class has reason to be more paranoid about child classes than its base, why should it assume that even though it could follow the base contract, sub-derived classes wouldn't be able to?  I would posit that a decision to seal or not seal classes should be made primarily on other bases.

Answer (score 5):

My view is that constructors should be light, not relying on external resources/etc that might throw an exception.  The constructor should do enough to verify Dispose() can be safely called.  Consider using containment instead of inheritance, or having a factory method do the work that might throw.

Comment: Containment doesn't provide substitutability, and factory methods don't really help with inheritance.  Even if a class doesn't have any public constructors and requires all instances *of that type* to be produced via factory method, the only way for any derived-type instances to be produced is via chained constructor, and there's no nice way to have a derived class constructor only be invokable via factory code in the base.  There are some ways, but they're icky.

Answer (score 2):

All derived class constructors must call `Dispose` on the object being constructed if they exit via an exception.  Further, it's very difficult to write leak-proof classes if field initializers construct `IDisposable` instances or can fail.  Too bad, since requiring objects to be declared in one place, initialized in a second, and cleaned up in a third is not exactly a recipe for coherent code.

I would suggest that the best pattern is probably something like:

```
class foo : baseFoo , IDisposable
{
    foo () : baseFoo
    {
        bool ok = false;
        try
        {
            do_stuff();
            ok = true; // Only after last thing that can cause failure
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!ok)
              Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that C++/CLI automatically implements that pattern, and can also automatically handle cleanup of IDisposable fields.  Too bad the language seems like a pain in other ways.

PS--With relatively few exceptions, mostly revolving around predictable-cost shared immutable objects (e.g. brushes, fonts, small bitmaps, etc.), code which relies upon `Finalize` to clean up objects is *broken*.  If an `IDisposable` is created, it must be disposed unless the code which created it has particular knowledge about the consequences of deferring disposal to a finalizer.

Comment: Isn't it a rule to not call virtual methods (Dispose() calls virtual method Dispose(bool) ) from a constructor?

Comment: @jimvfr: One should not call virtual methods *unless those methods are prepared for the possibility of being invoked on a partially-built object*.  It is in general easier and more reliable to require as part of a base-class contract that all subclasses must have their `Dispose` code be usable on partially-built objects (e.g. use a static SafeDispose method which calls `Dispose` on its target if non-null) and call `Dispose` on all construction failures, than to try to write code by hand which only examines and Disposes the `IDisposable` fields that have been set so far.

Comment: @jimvfr: This does to some extent presuppose that all the things that need cleanup implement `IDisposable` in such a way that calling `Dispose` more than once would be harmless, but Microsoft's documentation suggests that `IDisposable` objects are supposed to behave that way.  It doesn't go quite so far as to say that objects that do bad things when `Dispose` is called twice are "broken", but I see little reason in a GC system not to make all objects safe in the face of multiple `Dispose` calls.

Comment: It's not ideal to have to take such manual control of the object construction process but I don't see any better way of handling the situation than this answer. Assuming that any fields that might throw on initialization would be assigned in the 'try' block in the constructor then what's the problem with Disposing fields initialized by field initializers? Rather than checking a bool flag I'd instead execute constructor code in a 'try/catch all' block where the catch just calls Dispose and rethrows, as that's less code and marginally more efficient.

Comment: @Neutrino: One difficulty is that exceptions may occur in the base-class or derived-class constructor.  If a derived class initializes any `IDisposable` fields using field-initializer syntax, the only way provide for timely cleanup if the base constructor throws will be to have the base constructor call `Dispose`.  I don't think there's any reason a language couldn't allow a class to wrap the whole construction process in a try/catch block and call a user-specified method if it throws, but neither C# nor VB.NET does so.  BTW, I wish there were an access specifier for individual constructors...

Comment: ...which would specify that they should only be usable to construct instances of the exact type rather than subtypes (other constructors could be used for subtypes), though for that to really work the two kinds of constructors would have to have different names (rather than both being called `.ctor`) so as to allow a `protected` constructor to share the signature of an outside-callable one.

Comment: Ah yes I see, because the subclass initializers are evaluated before base class constructors (C++ is so much more logical in this respect). If the baseFoo constructor might throw, then it would also have to implement the same pattern you demonstrate in the Foo constructor. The virtual Dispose method would have to check whether each resource it attempts to dispose is actually initialized before calling its base implementation, which has the incidental benefit of making Dispose safe in the face of multiple calls so this is just good practice anyway.

Comment: In which case the only issue is if you subclass a third party class whose constructor might throw and which you have no control over. I provided a demonstration in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Managed resources, this should not be a problem, they will get Garbage Collected. For Unmanaged resources, make sure you have  a Finalizer defined for your object, that will ensure the Unmanaged resources are cleaned  up.

Also, throwing exceptions from a constructor is considered very bad manners, It's better to provide a Factory Method to do the construction and error handling or to equip your object with an Initialize method that will throw the actual exception. That way the construction always succeeds and you're not left with these type of issues.

---

Correct, Dispose isn't called by the Garbage Collector, but a Finalizer is, which in turn needs to call Dispose. It's a more expensive technique, except when used correctly. I didn't say so in my answer, did I ;).

You can call into the GC to force a collection run and you can wait for all pending finalizers. It's still better to not put the exception generating code in the construstor or by placing a try/catch around the code in the constructor to ensure Dispose is called on these files in case of an error. You can always rethrow the exception later.

Comment: (See my response to Frank Schwieterman) I'll use factory method

Comment: In my case the base class uses a few FileStreams which are a managed resource, but need to be disposed of immediately upon error, I can't wait for the files to close later.  Also the GC doesn't call Dispose.

Comment: A finalizer is supposed to only clean up unmanaged resources (i.e. have your finalizer method call Dispose(false)), so I don't see how a finalizer can clean up a managed resource.

Comment: In this case (which I would consider a bug in the design) you can make it call Dispose(true) to unlock the files.  Though it's better to just make sure the exception never happens in the constructor (or the files aren't opened in the constructor).

Comment: Agreed it's much better to make sure constructor can't throw, that's why I'm switching to factory method as I mentioned in first comment. Factory method will then call Initialize().

Comment: Garbage collection is not the issue, the issue is one of cleanup and that that can involve logic in addition to simple managed and unmanaged resources. Finalizers are called in a nonspecific order on the GC thread, which makes it a pretty useless location from which to attempt to perform cleanup, because most non-static managed objects are not thread safe, and attempting to safely cleanup a self referencing graph of objects when it is not safe to access any of those object's references is futile.

Comment: Factory Methods are methods defined by the client to select which concrete class of a hierarchy to instantiate. Using Factory Methods as a location for the client to perform any initialization of the object being created that might throw, and then having the client work out how to safely destroy the object if the object that gets created is broken sounds awful to me. Wouldn't that also require an additional mechanism to prevent multiple clients from having to duplicate that code?

Answer (score 0):

This solution builds on the proposal by @supercat. Initialization of any member that might throw must be performed in the constructor's try/catch block. With that condition met an exception thrown from any constructor will correctly dispose a fully or partially constructed base or derived class.

In this test code uncomment each of the four exceptions in turn and the program will output which of the Disposable resources were not disposed properly due to the constructor throwing an exception. Then uncomment the two Dispose calls and observe that everything gets cleaned up as it should.

```cs
    class DisposableResource : IDisposable
    {
        public DisposableResource(string id) { Id = id; }
        ~DisposableResource() { Console.WriteLine(Id + " wasn't disposed.\n"); }
        public string Id { get; private set; }
        public void Dispose() { GC.SuppressFinalize(this); }
    }

    class Base : IDisposable
    {
        public Base()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception();      // Exception 1.
                _baseCtorInit = new DisposableResource("_baseCtorInit");
//              throw new Exception();      // Exception 2.
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
//              Dispose();                  // Uncomment to perform cleanup.
                throw;
            }
        }

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            if (_baseFieldInit != null)
            {
                _baseFieldInit.Dispose();
                _baseFieldInit = null;
            }

            if (_baseCtorInit != null)
            {
                _baseCtorInit.Dispose();
                _baseCtorInit = null;
            }
        }

        private DisposableResource _baseFieldInit = new DisposableResource("_baseFieldInit");
        private DisposableResource _baseCtorInit;
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
        public Derived()
        {
            try
            {
//              throw new Exception();      // Exception 3.
                _derivedCtorInit = new DisposableResource("_derivedCtorInit");
//              throw new Exception();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
//              Dispose();                  // Uncomment to perform cleanup.
                throw;
            }
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            if (_derivedFieldInit != null)
            {
                _derivedFieldInit.Dispose();
                _derivedFieldInit = null;
            }

            if (_derivedCtorInit != null)
            {
                _derivedCtorInit.Dispose();
                _derivedCtorInit = null;
            }

            base.Dispose();
        }

        private DisposableResource _derivedFieldInit = new DisposableResource("_derivedFieldInit");
        private DisposableResource _derivedCtorInit;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Derived d = new Derived();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception.\n");
            }

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to continue...\n");
            Console.ReadKey(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest that you could eliminate some redundant code if you define a method `void DisposeAndClear<T>(ref T it) where T:class {T oldValue = Interlocked.Exchange(ref it, null); if (oldValue) oldValue.Dispose(); }`.  Then you can simple `DisposeAndClear` each field regardless of whether or not it's already null; further, even if `Dispose` somehow got called on multiple threads, each field would still only get disposed once.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I haven't added multi-threading support to my sample in order to keep demonstration of the key principle as simple as possible.

Comment: My key point wasn't the `Interlocked.Exchange`, but rather the fact that the per-field vertical space would be reduced from 6 lines (e.g. `if (_baseFieldInit)...`)  to one (e.g. `DisposeAndClear(ref _baseFieldInit);`).  Even with only two fields, I think the `DisposeAndClear` method would improve clarity since each field would be mentioned once rather than three times.  With every additional field, one would save another five lines of vertical space.  If a class has six fields, a disposal method whose body fits in six lines would IMHO be much more readable than one which takes 35.